# PHP CURL POST on a ASP.NET website

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to login to an ASP.NET website. I have the correct login, and I'm capturing the `__VIEWSTATE` variable with my initial load of the website form, but there's no `__EVENTVALIDATION` variable on the page, and I'm getting the following error when i try to perform the login:

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that `<machineKey>` configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Has anyone experienced this before? I assume it's because I'm missing the `__EVENTVALIDATION` variable, but why isn't it available to me?

Comment: If someone has any suggestion for tackling this, I would so greatly appreciate it. I'm using Fiddler to capture the communication ...